# Magento 2 - Add filter or join query in grid collection

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, filter

I created an admin grid using reference https://ranasohel.me/2014/04/20/creating-magento2-adminhtml-grid/.

Now I want to apply `addFieldToFilter()` of my collection in the grid.

How can I do this? Because Magento 2 use `ui_component` for the grid in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to create join in any grid then you need to existing grid collection. For this example, the grid has own collection. So you can add following code to grid collection.

File: `SR/Weblog/Model/ResourceModel/BlogPosts/Grid/Collection.php`

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->join(
        [$this->getTable('second_table_name')],
        'main_table.blogpost_id = '.$this->getTable('second_table_name').'.blogpost_id',
        array()
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Also, you can use:

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
{
}
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117352/31354. I am confused in this link question.plz need suggestion

Comment: I am getting  `a:4:{i:0;s:366:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `secondTable` ON main_table.entity_id = secondTable.parent_id AND secondTable.address_type="billing" WHERE  (`entity_id` IN('1'))"`

Comment: @zedBlackbeard Please post new question regarding your problem. It will be good to help with.

Comment: I have fixed that by overriding the fields name using `_construct` function. It is working now. Thanks for your response.