# Magento 2 better way create custom grid

Tags: magento2, grid, reports, order-grid

I found 2 website references for creating a custom grid.

1. https://ranasohel.me/2014/04/20/creating-magento2-adminhtml-grid/
2. http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html

The first link tutorial grid created like **sales > order** and the second link website tutorial of the grid is like **report > order total** grid in magento2.

what is the difference between their tutorials to create a custom grid?
Any limitation or benefit of the tutorials to create a grid?

Comment: You should concentrate about ui_component only. May be upcoming release other grid will be deprecated. This is another way of creating grid. You can create another way to create grid like M1. So forget every thing  without ui_component.

Comment: Yes you are right. Other developers also says that must be use ui_component but in magento2 report order total and report order count grid created without ui_compoent so therefore I confused

Comment: don't worry about that all are converted to ui_component in upcoming release.

Comment: Now as there is Magento ce 2.1 is released grid creation is managed using ui components and which is far better way.